# How set up iptables for Double VPN (VPN chain) with Wireguard?

Tags: vpn, iptables, wireguard

I'm currently trying to set up a VPN chain (double vpn) with using Wireguard. I tried to use examples from different articles: https://allanjohn909.medium.com/vpn-chaining-with-wireguard-ec2bd500509e https://habr.com/ru/articles/570160/
I have 2 servers: SV1 - all users connect to this one. SV2 - all traffic have to be redirected to this server and then directed to the any target website and etc.

I have created two Wireguard configs on SV1. wg0-client - to connect to the SV2. wg10 - to connect every user to the SV1.
**wg0-client.conf:**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = PrivateKey_of_SV1_for_server
Address = 192.168.0.2/32
MTU = 1420

[Peer]
PublicKey = PublicKey_of_SV2
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/8
Endpoint = IP_of_SV2:33333
PersistentKeepalive = 21
```

**wg10.conf**

```
[Interface]
Address = 172.16.0.1/24
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0-client -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg0-client -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 34567
PrivateKey = PrivateKey_of_SV1_for_users


[Peer]
PublicKey = PublicKey_Of_Usr1
AllowedIPs = 172.16.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = PublicKey_Of_Usr2
AllowedIPs = 172.16.0.3/32
On the SV2 I have only 1 config - wg1.conf
```

On the SV2 I have only 1 config - **wg1.conf:**

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.0.1/24
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 33333
PrivateKey = PrivateKey_Of_SV2

[Peer]
PublicKey = PublicKey_Of_SV1_for_server
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = PublicKey_Of_Usr1
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.3/32
```

I use on the SV1 **systemctl start wg-quick@wg10** and **wg-quick up wg0-client** and on the SV2 **systemctl start wg-quick@wg1** The servers have connection between each other. I can connect to any server. However, I can't connect to SV1 and get access to websites. I turned on **net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1**

I tried to use iptables to solve this problem. I have numeroue attempts.I tried to write something like this on the SV1. **1st attempt** - (at the moment, I had only one config to connect users and to connect to SV2):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.2/24 -o wg0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
```

**2nd attempt:**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.1 -o wg0-client -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.0.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wg10 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1
```

**3rd attempt:**

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg10 -o wg0-client -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg10 -o wg0-client -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**4th attempt:**

```
ip rule add table 200 from 172.16.0.1
ip rule add table 200 from 172.16.0.2
ip rule add table table 200 default via 192.168.0.1
```

**5th attempt:**

```
ip rule add table 200 from 172.16.0.2
ip rule add table table 200 default via 192.168.0.1
```

**6th attempt:**

```
ip rule add table 200 from 172.16.0.2
ip rule add table table 200 default via 192.168.0.2
```

Nothing have worked. I didn't received connection to any website, when I was connected to SV1 as a user. Can you suggest something? I use Ubuntu 20.04 for both servers.